# Is it okay to put external files inside my web application?

Tags: jsp, file-upload

I have the need to show some pdf files on my application, the user will upload and assign them to an entity. And then the user will be able to access those files through the application. My question is, those files than I’m planning to store in the server, should I put them in a different directory? Or is it okay if I include them inside the web directory? 
I'm using jsp and tomcat by the way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No matter where you put the directory to store PDF files. Although some applications recommend to use a different directory, the most important is to control the permissions of that specific directory in which you want to store PDFs.